# How do you export a specific source file in webpack?

Tags: json, vue.js, webpack

I have a file called `src/services/data.json` which I use to populate some data for one of my services.  I use the following

```
import embeddedData from "./data.json";
```

to import the file.   When I generate the distribution, as expected the contents are merged in so they're not in the resulting `dist` folder

Is there something I can do to the webpack configuration so it will export JSON data files?  (I'm using vue with TypeScript for my framework)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Dynamic Imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports). Webpack will create separate files for such imports by default. In runtime those files are asynchronously loaded. Webpack 
 transforms `import()` calls to [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you can use await/async as well.

Comment: That didn't work because it generates the JSON file as JavaScript. I want it to remain JSON.

Comment: Ahh, i see. Then maybe your best bet might be just using the `file-loader` for this asset. It should emit the file to your `dist` folder.